# xcodebuild using Ld rather than Clang for linking

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a strange issue with a react native project. Building the project in XCode works fine, but building at the command line throws a strange error. Specifically this invocation (where values in <..> are replaced with real values)

```sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace <workspace name>.xcworkspace -configuration <configuration> -scheme <schema> -sdk iphonesimulator13.6
```

Throws this strange error when linking the application:

```sh
ld: unknown option: -target
```

Now this seems to be because the linking step is called like this:

```sh
Ld /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project derviced data directory> normal x86_64 (in target '<target>' from project '<project>')
    cd /<project direvtory>
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -L <list of libraries included>
```

What seems strange about this step is the it is using `ld` whereas in the build log in XCode this step is

```sh
Ld /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project derived data directory> normal x86_64 (in target '<Target>' from project '<project>')
    cd /<project directory>
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -L <libraries>
```

The difference being that XCode appears to be linking using clang, whereas xcodebuild is linking using ld. Anyone any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you running in a non standard build environment? 

I have this issue too, but it only surfaces when I'm trying to build via the nix package manager. If I run the same `xcodebuild` command directly, it works. I have no further  insight… but curious if it's also related to a non standard build environment, which may lead to clues! :D

Comment: Yeah I'm also using nix, but even running `xcodebuild` outside of a `nix-shell` causes issues.

Comment: Interesting. The two I'm having issues with work without issue outside of nix…

One builds with `xcodebuild`, the other with `swift`. 

In the swift package, I noticed that if `arch` is specified, e.g. `--arch x86_64 --arch arm64`, it triggers the issue, but if no arch is specified, it builds ok inside nix. There is a sandbox issue too, but I just disabled sandbox to ignore that for now.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this problem and I think I found a solution that works. What tipped me off was [this comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/7062e5519bdeae9f3535787f5f8a225ccc231b11/pkgs/development/mobile/xcodeenv/build-app.nix#L92) in the `build-app.nix`. While in my nix shell running `export LD="/usr/bin/clang"` (and cleaning the xcode DerivedData build cache), allowed me to build my project. I use `direnv` so I added the export in my `.envrc` after my `use flake`.